# Should I post here plugins compatibility research?

Tags: discussion

Right now I'm creating a multilingual event site. I'm lazy to write the plugin myself. I have scrutinized half-dozen of top event organizer plugins in a tow with the *Polylang* plugin which I'm in love with.

Most of the event managers hold the multilingual capability only partially, each and every of them has their own bugs and schticks in connection with *Polylang*.

I have the research information which I want to share. This information is generally in the strict sense, but it could be helpful for the people trying to find a similar solution.

Should I post **the wall** of research results to WPSE as self-accepted question?

Comment: This sounds like something that would fit on https://comparewp.org/

Comment: Unambiguously no. The question is to post or not to post.

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is, do you mean to post research results as a question? If so what's the question, is it to recommend based on the research provided? Or do you mean to post as an answer and let the user decide for themselves? If so how does it answer their question? Some clarification needed

Comment: Yes, as a self-accepted question. No recommendations, no links. Just an information to help people to choose among. But I'm not sure about convenience about such an action. The question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that you asked this up front :) There is no such thing like a self accepted answer, just a self asked and answered question. If it is crystal clear to you, that you will accept your own answer, then the question itself is opinionated, which is a good sign that there might be a fitting close reason that the community may make use of.

Anyway, I would recommend you—from a self-marketing view point—that you put your research in a **Medium** article or ask Brian from **PostStatus** or Sarah/Jeff from **WPTavern** if you have some room there. **Smashing Magazine** would be another option—where @toscho is their chief editor for the WordPress topic.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I didn't think about other channels to post the research and got stuck on WPSE. I'll take a look more closely at the list you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd very much like such information in WPSE. Even though I'm fairly new to WPSE, my suggestion is:

> Follow the `Jetpack` route. Find a way to `expand` or even `cheat` the rules for the greater good.

For example: if you ask if plugin `a` supports plugin `b` on `xyz` grounds, then many may vote it as off topic.

However, if you post 6 different questions, each with some examples saying that plugin `a1`, (`a2`, `a3` etc.) doesn't follow `xyz` WordPress standards (e.g. internationalization. localization etc.) and ask the community if anyone can provide a complete list of such violation of standards or an idea to compile such a list for customizing that plugin according to `xyz` WP standards, then it may fall under `WordPress development` or `Plugin Development` topics.

You don't even need to mention about plugin `a1`'s support for plugin `b`. As long as plugin `b` follows WP standards, asking for those relevant WP standards should be enough.

Also, to avoid the `too broad` topic trap, instead of asking for a complete list of issues under `xyz` standards that plugin `a1` doesn't follow, you may ask how to look for such violations of standards in plugin `a1`. Then no one can complain if you yourself provide the complete research data as an answer (without asking for it in the question).

For example: there is a `t1` theme in Github that doesn't follow WP theme repository standards. To get it approved in WP theme repo, you need to check it with the `theme check` plugin, follow requirements set by `Theme Review Handbook` etc. etc. - now if you can figure out the appropriate question for this answer, then I'm sure you can also figure out half a dozen appropriate questions for your own research data.

These are just examples, use your own imagination to make the questions on topic. You may be surprised by other answers the community comes up with over time (if you can ask the right question). As one of my Physics teachers in university always used to say:

> being able to ask the right question is part of the answer.

---

**Rant:**

Any community that is not flexible enough will collapse. As [this doc.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) clearly states:

> We don’t run this site. The community does.

So this site will become whatever WPSE `community` evolves into.